# How to pass string parameters with jquery $.get()

Tags: jquery, parameters

I am a newbee to jquery and modifying someone's code to send a string parameter in the following call. I am not sure how to pass a string parameter - myarray where myarray = (1111,2222,3333). I have tried it without quotes, and ~(myarray) which did not work. Please help.

```
$j.get("modhelper.html", "id="myarray"&dcid=~[tlist_sql;select dcid from customers where id = ~(curid);]~(dcid)[/tlist_sql]&transdate="+$j(this).val(), function(data)
```

Comment: i think this is ajax.. maybe you could give rest of code..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use an object with key value pairs as the 2nd property to the .get() method

```
$j.get('modhelper.html', {
        id: 'myarray',
        dcid: '~~[tlist_sql;select dcid from customers where id = ~(curid);]~(dcid)[/tlist_sql]',
        transdate: $j(this).val()
    },
    function(data){
        //console.log(data);
    }
);
```